# Бот для группы Вконтакте не работает

Tags: вконтакте, бот

Ошибок никаких не выдаёт, однако бот в вк не отвечает. Токен и id группы точно верны. Не могу понять что не так.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from data import token, group_id

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id)


def sender(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})


while True:
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id)
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            msg = event.object.message['text'].lower()
            if event.to_me:
                id = event.user_id
                if msg == 'привет':
                    sender(id, 'здравствуй')
```

Comment: random_id должен быть случайным, а не ноль

Comment: подскажи как это можно сделать